# How can I enumerate sets of inequalities that give a nonempty feasible region?

Tags: linear-programming, geometric-inequalities, algebraic-combinatorics

My goal is this. I have variables $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \geq 0$. I also must choose a set of inequalities. My choices are as follows:

$\forall S \subseteq [n]$, choose $\sum \limits _{i \in S} a_i \geq 1$ or $\sum \limits _{i \in S} a_i < 1$.

How can I make a list of the sets of choices that give me a consistent set of inequalities, that is, a set of inequalities with a nonempty feasible region?

For example, if I have $a_1, a_2$ the list of sets of choices would look like this:

$1. a_1 \geq 1, a_2 \geq 1, a_1 + a_2 \geq 1 \\
2.a_1 \geq 1, a_2 < 1, a_1 + a_2 \geq 1 \\
3. a_1 < 1, a_2 \geq 1, a_1 + a_2 \geq 1 \\
4. a_1 < 1, a_2 < 1, a_1+a_2 \geq 1 \\
5. a_1 < 1, a_2 < 1, a_1 + a_2 < 1 \\
$

because each set of inequalities on this list is consistent.

My list would not include $a_1 \geq 1, a_2 \geq 1, a_1 + a_2 < 1$, for example, because this set of inequalities in inconsistent given the constraints.

It is not as simple as randomly choosing for each subset of $[n]$. For example, if I have $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$, I cannot simultaneously choose

$a_1 + a_2 \geq 1$

$a_3 + a_4 \geq 1$

$a_1 + a_3 < 1$

$a_1 + a_4 < 1$

$a_2 + a_4 < 1$

$a_2 + a_3 < 1$

because I know that one of $a_1,a_2$ is at least $1/2$, and also one of $a_3,a_4$ is at least $1/2$.

I have tried to come up with a recursive enumeration, but even for a small number of variables, the number of possibilities seems to get out of control quickly. I've also thought about using the simplex algorithm by putting an artificial variable in each $\geq$ inequality and trying to minimize the sum of the artificial variables, but it's not clear how I could apply this to the general case. I've also thought about enumerating regions using a list of vertices, which I can find by taking sets of inequalities as equations and finding unique intersections, but in certain cases, a feasible region does not contain any of its vertices.

I feel like there should be an easy answer to this question, but for some reason I can't come up with anything. I believe this problem is related to algebraic combinatorics, but I can't find anything in the resources that I have to answer this question. By the way, this is not homework; this is just something related to a problem I came up with in graph theory.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: (1) Use a binary variable to enable/disable a constraint, and then use a MIP solver to find a solution. Add a cut to forbid the current solution and repeat. When the solver can no longer find a feasible solution you are done.  (2) automate this using the solution pool technology available in solvers like Cplex and Gurobi.

Comment: So then how do I find a solution for $n$ variables? Are you suggesting that I look at the data and try to find a pattern?

Comment: I don't understand your point. The MIP solver will find a solution (if it exists).

Comment: Does an MIP solver give solutions in terms of general $n$ when $n$ is not fixed? I feel like what you're telling me only works for fixed values of $n$, which is not what I'm interested in. 

Maybe I don't understand what you're saying correctly, but I feel like this is like if I asked how to count the number of spanning trees on a general graph, and you tell me to use a search algorithm when what I really need is the Matrix Tree Theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying here,

Comment: I edited the wording to try to make it clearer. The reason that I can't just use a program to give me the list is that I'm interested in a theoretical solution for a general $n$.